# PHP doesn't post to DB from data entered in form?

Tags: php, mysql

I can't see the problem here. I enter data in my input cells and after submit it only refresh a page and do not post anything in the MySQL. I'm doing this by watching online tutorial which is old, so maybe there are some old methods, that could be a problem.

```
<?php
        include "../db/connect.php";
        if (isset($_POST['pavadinimas'])) {

            $pavadinimas = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pavadinimas']);
            $kaina = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['kaina']);
            $info = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['info']);
            $gamintojas = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['gamintojas']);
            $gamintojas = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['atmintis']);
            $tipas = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['tipas']);
            $kiekis = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['kiekis']);
            // See if that product name is an identical match to another product in the system
            $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM prekes WHERE pavadinimas='$pavadinimas' LIMIT 1");
            $productMatch = mysqli_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
            if ($productMatch > 0) {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("KLAIDA! Bandėte įkelti prekę, kurios pavadinimas jau yra įrašytas duomenų bazėje.");</script>';
                exit();
            }
            // Add this product into the database now
            $sql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO prekes (pavadinimas, kaina, info, gamintojas, atmintis, tipas, kiekis, laikas) 
                VALUES('$pavadinimas','$kaina','$info','$gamintojas','$atmintis','$tipas','$kiekis',now())") or die (mysqli_error($con));
             $pid = mysqli_insert_id();
            // Place image in the folder 
            $newname = "$pid.jpg";
            move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$newname");
            header("location: itemList.php"); 
            exit();
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Please read up on SQL injection before you put this on the internet. You need to put protection into your inputs.

Comment: Where is your HTML?

Comment: Without any error messages/logs, it is difficult to diagnose any specific problems, are there are a few possibilities.  Please turn on error logging in your php engine and post any error output.

Comment: VALUES ('".$name."') try like this

Comment: Are you sure there is a post variable pavadinimas? You can see the content of `$_POST` array with `var_dump($_POST)` before the if statement.

Comment: @Joel I put this now for errors: <?php 
// Script Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?> it doesn't show anything.

Comment: @webpic that didn't work.

Comment: you are getting any errors ?? and what does `$pid` returns

Comment: error reporting is turned on using your php.ini.   Do a google search on php.ini error reporting

Comment: @webpic that is the problem, I don't get any errors, it just reloads page with empty form cells.

Comment: try one thing write query "insert" into one variable $sql and print that query , and see what it is printing and post here

Answer (score 0):

There was just a dumb mistake. In html SUBMIT button name was set to 'button', not submit, so it didn't post it to the database.

and this

```
if (isset($_POST['pavadinimas']))
```

should have been this

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```